# The fingerprint generated with fingerprintjs is unstable

Tags: javascript, fingerprint, fingerprintjs2, fingerprintjs

I use fingerprintjs to generate browser fingerprints, but the fingerprints change during debugging and are irregular.

Comment: So... your question is... how make them consistent?

Comment: Yes, brother, do you have a solution？

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options.

A) You can exclude built-in entropy components that cause instability among your audience (or you can even add new custom entropy components) like

```
const result = await fp.get()

// The `languages` and `audio` components will be excluded
const { languages, audio, ...components } = result.components

// Optinally, you can make a visitor identifier from your custom list of components
const visitorId = FingerprintJS.hashComponents(components)
```

You can learn more about this option in the [GitHub docs](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs/blob/master/docs/extending.md).

B) You can use more precise [FingerprintJS Pro](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs#upgrade-to-pro-version-to-get-995-identification-accuracy) (commercial product with a free tier).

Comment: useful code snippet to get a better sense on what parameters are controllable within fingerprintjs